# How can a value of a value type in a dictionary be modified through an optional of it?

Tags: swift, option-type

Array and optional types are both a value type in Swift. As exhibited in the following example, one can't modify an array through an optional of it.

```
var a = [1, 2]
var aOptional: [Int]? = a
aOptional![1] = 100
```

`a` remains to be `[1, 2]` though the array wrapped in aOptional is changed to `[1, 100]`.

With that said, can anyone explain to me how can the following piece of code work?

```
var testScores = ["Dave": [86, 82, 84]]
testScores["Dave"]![0] = 91
```

It produces the result that the "Dave" array in `testScores` to be [91, 82, 84]. The "Dave" array inside `testScores` is modified through an optional of it, `testScores["Dave"]`. How is this possible?

Comment: Array in Swift are value type not reference type both a and aOptional are point to different reference not the same.

Comment: @NiravD you should make that an answer

Comment: @NiravD The part you just mentioned makes sense to me. What I don't understand is the that `testScores["Dave"]!` and the "Dave" array in `testScores` seem to be the same object while `a` and `aOptional!` are not the same object. Since I can't find a way to actually wrap an object of a value type, Array<Int> in this case, inside an optional but a copy of it, I wonder how can the optional of `testScores["Dave"]` wraps the "Dave" array in `testScores`.

Comment: @candleindark There is a big difference in both of your example, first one when you extract the array from dictionary it will point to the same address you are just wrapping the optional if you do the same thing using if let it will not change the dictionary.

Comment: @candleindark i think it can be related to the way the memory assignation internally works, based on doc u can see that even the existing value is returned when you subscript the dictionary, therefore it's not a new var that is being created (and since it's a value type therefore copy ), it's like if you were operating on the array itself.  " If the dictionary contains a value for the requested key, the subscript returns an optional value containing the existing value for that key" . Iimplementation of NSDictionary internally is also pointing in the same dir in my opinion

Comment: https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/6cda1f30f4d2e33e426d52eaa8c99aa1c415c4a6/Foundation/NSDictionary.swift

Comment: @BarbaraRodeker Thanks for the response. You are the first responder actually knows what I am asking. However, my question remains unanswered. An optional in Swift is a value type, i.e. it is a copy of a value. So, in that sense, the value, `testScores["Dave"]!`, wrapped inside `testScores["Dave"]` should be a copy of the "Dave" array in `testScores`, and changing `testScores["Dave"]!` shouldn't change the "Dave" array in `testScores`. How come this behavior is not the observed behavior of Dictionary? It seems, as if, Swift has violated the rule of an optional being a value type in this case.

Comment: @candleindark if that's the case , that would be as you suggest, and I was pointing in a similar direction mentioning a possible specific / different internal memory handling under the hood... but to really know that I think the best direction is to jump into the open sourced code and check how testScores["Dave"] is working internally

Answer (score 2):

Array in Swift are value type not reference type both a and aOptional are point to different address not the same. You can confirm it using printing address.

```
var a = [1, 2]
var aOptional: [Int]? = a
aOptional![1] = 100
withUnsafePointer(to: &a) {
    print("Array \(a) has address: \($0)")
}
withUnsafePointer(to: &aOptional) {
    print("Array \(aOptional) has address: \($0)")
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array [1, 2] has address: 0x00007fff5f6c2ae8
Array Optional([1, 100]) has address: 0x00007fff5f6c2ae0
//Both are pointing different memory address
```

Now with your dictionary you are wrapping the optional with `!` and changing the value of same array if you assign it different array then result will same like `a` and `aOptional`.

```
var testScores = ["Dave": [86, 82, 84]]
withUnsafePointer(to: &testScores["Dave"]!) {
    print("Address: \($0)")
}
testScores["Dave"]![0] = 91
print(testScores)
var array = testScores["Dave"]!
array[0] = 100
withUnsafePointer(to: &array) {
    print("New Array Address: \($0)")
}
print(testScores)
```

**Output:**

```
Address: 0x00007fff5a442ac0
["Dave": [91, 82, 84]]
New Array Address: 0x00007fff5a442ae0
["Dave": [91, 82, 84]] //As you can see array's first object is still 91
```

Comment: I understand that `a` and `aOptional!` are different objects, and `testScores["Dave"]!` and the "Dave" array in `testScores` are the same object. My question is how can `testScores["Dave"]!` and the "Dave" array in `testScores` be the same object? As you pointed out, arrays are value type in Swift. So, it follows that `testScores["Dave"]!` should be just a copy of the "Dave" array in `testScores` contained in the optional, `testScores["Dave"]`.

Comment: @candleindark You are still not getting it, let me edit my answer with one more example

Comment: @candleindark try to forget about optionals for a moment. It is really only about value vs reference types. Being optional has nothing to do with this functionality.

Comment: @candleindark Have you checked that link https://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/592bbf850dd2416a316ac9c8? Is it clear now?

Comment: @NiravD Well, first thank you for the help, but I am still not clear. What you are telling me is pretty much what I already suspect, and it is not what I am looking for. I know the nature of value types. However, in looking through the examples, I have come to the idea that the values in arrays in Swift are stored inside optionals. Is that the case? I have no proof of it, but it seems to match the behaviors that we have seen.

Comment: @candleindark No values or elements inside array is not optional until you specify it as optional like `var strings = [String?]()`, Here each elements of array is optional but not the array strings is optional now lets take another ex `var strings: [String]? = [String]()` here elements of array is not optional but array its self optional and if you do face optional chaining then elements of array is also optional. Now in your case when you subscript dictionary it will always return optional object reason is that if there is no key in dictionary that you are subscript then it will return `nil`.

Comment: @NiravD Thank you for spending so much time in helping me. However, your answers unfortunately do not address what I am asking. Barbara Rodeker actually understands what I am asking. You can take a look at our conversation above to find out more about my question if you are still interested in helping.